# Getting No generic method 'where' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments

Tags: c#, .net, json, expression-trees

I have been writing expression tree for creating lambda expressions dynamically.

To start it up small, I am reading data from a JSON file into an Class object. And trying to build the where condition on two conditions.

```
string jsonnew = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\nested_Json.txt");

var rootObject1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Citizen>(jsonnew);

IEnumerable<Citizen> enumerable = new[] { rootObject1 };

IQueryable<Citizen> queryableDataaa = enumerable.AsQueryable();

        ParameterExpression pe1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "rootobject");

        PropertyInfo field = typeof(Citizen).GetProperty("name");
        PropertyInfo field2 = typeof(Citizen).GetProperty("id");
        ParameterExpression targetExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Citizen), "rootobject");
        ParameterExpression valueExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "\"StrozeR\"");
        ParameterExpression valueExp2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Int32),"1765116");
        MemberExpression fieldExp = Expression.Property(targetExp, field);
        MemberExpression fieldExp2 = Expression.Property(targetExp, field2);
       Expression assignExp = Expression.Equal(fieldExp, valueExp);
       Expression assignExp2 = Expression.Equal(fieldExp2, valueExp2);

Expression predicateBody1 = Expression.AndAlso(assignExp, assignExp2);

MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression1 = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            "where",
            new Type[] { queryableDataaa.ElementType},
            queryableDataaa.Expression,
            Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(predicateBody1, new ParameterExpression[] { pe1 }));
```

Can anyone help me out in understand why I am getting

> No generic method 'where' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic. error

Answer (score 4):

You must

- use constant expressions for your values
- use one argument with type `Citizen` for the whole where clause expression
- find the `Where`(with capital w) method of `IQueryable` where is an extension method defined in `System.Linq.Queryable`, then provide it's generic type
- invoke the method with appropriate parameters

here is the corrected code:

```
var targetExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Citizen), "rootobject");
var valueExp = Expression.Constant("\"StrozeR\"");
var valueExp2 = Expression.Constant(1765116);
var fieldExp = Expression.Property(targetExp, "name");
var fieldExp2 = Expression.Property(targetExp, "id");
var assignExp = Expression.Equal(fieldExp, valueExp);
var assignExp2 = Expression.Equal(fieldExp2, valueExp2);
var predicateBody1 = Expression.AndAlso(assignExp, assignExp2);

var queryableType = typeof(System.Linq.Queryable);
var whereMethod = queryableType.GetMethods()
       .First(m =>
       {
           var parameters = m.GetParameters().ToList();
           //Put more restriction here to ensure selecting the right overload                
           //the first overload that has 2 parameters
           return m.Name == "Where" && m.IsGenericMethodDefinition &&
                 parameters.Count == 2;
       });
var whereClause = Expression.Lambda<Func<Citizen, bool>>(predicateBody1, 
                  new ParameterExpression[] { targetExp });
var genericMethod = whereMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Citizen));
var newQuery = (IQueryable<Citizen>)genericMethod
              .Invoke(genericMethod, new object[] { queryableDataaa, whereClause });
```

Answer (score 2):

To get Where, try something like:

```
var where = new Func<IQueryable<int>, Expression<Func<int, bool>>, IQueryable<int>>(Queryable.Where).Method;
```

if you want it with a runtime type, do

```
var whereForMyType = where.GetGenericMethodDefinition().MakeGenericMethod(myType);
```

where myType is your type.